# Linux command line based spam checker?

Tags: linux, email, command-line-interface, spam

Does a command line based spam checker exist?

We have created a mailbox at a 3rd party, and unfortunately decided on spam checking 'disabled' in the initial setup.

There is no way to re-enable spam checking, the mailbox must be delete (and thus all contents lost) and re-created.

Does anything exist where we can pump in either:

**A) Subject + from + to + body + all other fields.**

OR

**B) Raw message dump (headers + body).**

And the command line will let us know weather the email is possibly spam?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may be looking for [SpamAssassin](http://spamassassin.apache.org/). It uses various mechanisms for identifying spam, including text analysis, Bayesian filtering, DNS blocklists, and collaborative filtering databases.

Answer (score 1):

[bogofilter](http://bogofilter.sourceforge.net/) might be another option.